# What does Integration with an Issue Tracking System do in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, redmine, issue-tracking

There is an article [`Enabling Integration with an Issue Tracking System`](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/enabling-integration-with-an-issue-tracking-system.html) in IntelliJ docs.

It describes how to "integrate" `IntelliJ` with Issue Tracking System.

But what it actually does?

I have Redmine installed and have added an issue to its "issues" page. Now I can browse issues on Redmine server. But what about IntelliJ? How to see that issue in it?

Comment: What?  You mean that this champion buzzword bingo explanation ''*integration ... allows you to work on your project in the discourse of tasks and contexts and thus set up your workflow in accordance with the process established in your team.*'' wasn't sufficient motivation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you integrate an Issue Tracking System then you can create a Task for each issue.

If you have VCS enabled for the project while creating a Task a Change list can be created in the VCS with the same name. So all the changes you do for the Task will be grouped in the change list.

For more please check [Opening and Creating Tasks](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/opening-and-creating-tasks.html).

Comment: Can I see an issue I have added from web page?

Comment: Yes. You should be able to see those issues.

Comment: Where? What is the window name for this?

Comment: @SuzanCioc if you open ```Tools -> Tasks&Contexts -> Open Task``` it should list all the issue then on select of an issue Open Task dialog will open.